# How to force Testdrive to use zsync?

Tags: testing, testdrive

While using testdrive gui, how to configure it to use zsync?

There seems to be no option to change that. Or is there a config file somewhere which can be edited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestDrive will use rsync, and then zsync, and then wget by default.

If you'd like to force zsync, I think that's a reasonable configuration option we should support.  You're welcome to file a bug against the TestDrive project in Launchpad, http://launchpad.net/testdrive.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

After some googling [1](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/02/testdrive-automatically-downloads-and.html) it seems testdrive will use zsync by default as long it's installed.

Update:
I have checked testdrive's source, it will use zsync if it can find the zsync command and if the image url starts with either http or ftp .

Comment: Are you sure? Why I'm doubtful is because: every-time I use testdrive, for a 2day old iso, the whole iso is downloaded again. It starts from 0% but when I use zsync it starts from 50% or 60% even when the iso is 1week to 10days old. This was the main reason why I thought it wasn't using zsync. Or is something else wrong...